# Change min-height of a div to browser height

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div for my content on my page with an id of "wrapper" (see [curtainandblinddevotion.co.uk](http://www.curtainandblinddevotion.co.uk)). There is also a nav bar at the top and a footer at the bottom.

I need the wrapper to be the height of the browser window, minus the height of the nav and footer. How do I do this with javascript?

The point of the script is so that large browser windows dont have the footer floating away from the bottom, and the wrapper's background should strech right to the footer.

Thanks in advance for any help,

Connor

Comment: `$('element').css('min-height', $(window).height() - $('nav').height())` etc

Comment: This seems to concern the general styling of your page. Are you sure you want to depend on Javascript for this?

Comment: I'm open to a CSS solution for it but it needs to take into account browser height and the footer should be at the bottom of the page even on large screens

Comment: @cwyatt1 You should include the minimal code necessary to reproduce the issue *in the question itself*. That way when the situation is fixed the question can still be useful to others

Comment: @Zach, Fair point, I'll try to add it in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I am going to give you a very basic example of how to keep the footer always bottom even in a big screens. [Read Here to Know more about How it Works](http://www.cssreset.com/how-to-keep-footer-at-bottom-of-page-with-css/)

**HTML**

```
 <div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header">My Header</div>
    <div id="content">My Content</div>
    <div id="footer">This my footer</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body {
margin:0;
padding:0;
height:100%;
}
#wrapper {
min-height:100%;
position:relative;
}
#header {
padding:10px;
background:green;
}
#content {
padding:10px;
padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */
}
#footer {
width:100%;
height:80px;
position:absolute;
bottom:0;
left:0;
background:red;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wK9CA/)

Comment: Thank you, works perfectly, I couldn't figure out a CSS solution. Thanks again, Connor

Answer (score 0):

I just created this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5ur87/

If your goal is to make the footer always at the bottom of the page even on large screens, you can use `position:fixed;` with `bottom:0px;`, like below:

```
footer{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 20px;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this works for a different project of mine, but I needed the footer to not always be snapped to the bottom of the screen, Thank you again for your help, it will be useful